# Questions about Dynkin system (i.e. $\lambda$-system)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

I am currently reading the book "Probability Theory:A Comprehensive Course" by Achim Klenke,in which there is a theorem left as an exercise for the reader.

### Definition 1:

Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set,and let $\mathcal A$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$.Then $\mathcal A$ is a Dynkin system if

(i) $\Omega \in \mathcal A$,

(ii) $A ^c \in \mathcal A$ if $A \in \mathcal A$,

(iii) If $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ is a sequence of subsets in $\mathcal A$ such that $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$,then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal A$.

### Definition 2 :

Let $\mathcal A \subset 2^\Omega$ be an arbitrary class of subsets of $\Omega$ and let $A \in 2^\Omega \backslash \{ \emptyset \}$
.The class

$\mathcal A \vert _A := \{ A \cap B:B \in \mathcal A \} \subset 2^A$

is called the trace of $\mathcal A$ on $A$.

### Theorem:

Let $A \subset \Omega$ be nonempty and let $\mathcal A$ be a Dynkin system on $\Omega$,then $\mathcal A \vert _A$ is not necessarily a Dynkin system on $A$ unless $A=\Omega$.

---

**My Question:**

The theorem stated above is the second half of the desired theorem from the book,and I failed in finding a counterexample that violates the third axiom of the so-called Dynkin system to complete the proof.

Can someone show me a counterexample? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your definition of a Dynkin system?

Comment: @Math1000 Sure,I have added the definition of Dynkin system,which was cited from Wikipedia.Thanks for pointing out this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$,  $\mathcal A=\{\varnothing, \{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\Omega\}$,  $A = \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!But I still want to know if there are some tricks of constructing such counterexamples.Sometimes I just don't know how to find a counterexample.

Comment: @RH_L, no tricks. You take some subsets that intersect in $\mathcal A$ ($\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,4\}$ in my example) but omit their intersection from $A$, as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question has already been answered, but for anyone else wondering, Klenke (in the 3rd edition of the book) basically gives 75% of the answer, if you look carefully. Exercise 1.11 (x) on p. 4 gives $\Omega$ and $\mathcal A$ such that $\mathcal A$ is a $\lambda$-system. Fiddle around with a set $A \subset \Omega$ and see if you can break one of the conditions of a $\lambda$-system. It's not hard.